# AWS CloudFormation template validation error when using sed command with backslash

Tags: sed, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to add deployment-related variables to an AWS lambda serverless-output.yaml file, by adding several lines to the file via an AWS CloudFormation template.

I have the following sed command:

```
sed -ie '/^    Properties:/a\      Tags:' ./serverless-output.yaml
```

When I run at command line in amazon linux it does as expected and adds the Tags: line correctly indented under the Properties: line

```
EC2StartStop:
  Properties:
    Tags:
```

When I put the line in the cloudformation template, I get a format error:

```
"sed -ie '/^    Properties:/a\      Tags:' ./serverless-output.yaml",

Error
Template validation error: Template format error: JSON not well-formed.
(line 200, column 36)
```

To get rid of the error, it appears I have to remove the backslash after the '/a':

```
"sed -ie '/^    Properties:/a    Tags:' ./serverless-output.yaml"
```

But then the Tags: line does not get indented, causing syntax error in .yaml file:

```
  EC2StartStop:
    Properties:
Tags:
```

The sed command works well for identifying the location i need to insert the lines, but how can I get the proper indentation on inserted lines when running command via cloudformation?

Comment: you'd be better off using yaml parsers...  I don't know about `cloudformation template`... best I could guess is perhaps you need ``\\`` ?

Comment: Thank you Sundeep - \\ fixed me.
    "sed -ie '/^    Properties:/a\\      Tags:' ./serverless-output.yaml \n",
  EC2StartStop:
    Properties:
      Tags:
Post as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about `cloudformation template` rules, but usually double quoted strings allow `\` to be used for special sequences, to allow non-printable characters with their oct/hex representation, etc. For ex: `\"` for representing double quote character within the quotes. So, to represent `\` it would need `\\`

```
"sed -ie '/^    Properties:/a\\      Tags:' ./serverless-output.yaml",
```